# Returning single ID in JSON from a web service

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net, json, web-services

I'm fairly new to working with client-side coding and was wondering what the the best way of returning a single ID from a simple Insert in a web service would be.

Copying code that returns more complex JSON objects, I'm doing the following:

```
        Dim JaggedArray As String()() = New String(0)() {}
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        JaggedArray(i) = New String() {<insert stmt, returns integer>}

        Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim strJSON As String = js.Serialize(JaggedArray)
        Return strJSON
```

I then use the following to access the ID in Javascript (excerpt from the AJAX call):

```
success: function(data) {
var c = eval(data.d);
var testID = c[0][0];
```

Surely there's a less clunky way of doing this, right?

And this is a stupid question, but can (and / or should) you put code outside of the Success callback, or is this mandatory?

Comment: Of course you can put code outside the success callback, but you might not be able to access the response. Also, what are you referring to by *"Surely there's a less clunky way of doing this, right?"*? If you don't like the nested array (`c[0][0]`), then you have to structure your data differently.

Comment: The structure is more or less the heart of my question.  Like I mentioned, I just copied the above code b/c I had the need to do a client-side insert, but it was for a JSON object, not a single integer.  Again, my experience to this point has been limited, and I'm teaching myself as I go along, so I'm probably missing out on a lot of fundamentals that get taken for granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you can use jqXHR.done An alternative construct to the success callback option, the **.done()**,

for more info visit http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
  $.ajax({
    //ajax stuff ..
  })
  .done(function(return){
    var output = "hello";
    return output;
  });
```